# Dynamic thread creation possible problems or safe approach

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am using java for socket programming, I am using two dynamic thread sets

#### First for accepting client request... Creation of thread dynamically for each client

```
try (ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(1000)) {
   while (true) {
   Socket socket = listener.accept();
   logger.debug(socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString() + " Has joined :::");
   new ThreadPool(socket).start();
  }
}
```

#### And second one is accepting client packets which they are sending and create new thread for parsing client data

```
public void run() { // this run() in ThreadPool class
    while (true) {
    new parserThread();//creating new thread for parsing information
   }
}
```

But my problem is after long time like 24 hr my application getting stuck and doesn't printing anything in console. I don't no why it's getting stuck but I have few doubts with my coding approach. Tell me whether those are the possibilities or not.

1. Creating thread in another dynamic thread.
2. Thread name allocation problem because it's increasing like :

> 549790 [Thread-17569]
>   549791 [Thread-17570] 
>   549792 [Thread-17571]
>
> Log4j console appender problem.
>
> Please correct me if I am wrong. Is ExecutorService with CountDownLatch is better approach then that one ?Thank you very much

Comment: Sounds like your parser thread is not terminating on client close?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jstack` utility from standard JRE installation to obtain stack traces for running Java application.  Stack traces will tell you where exactly you application stuck.  Once you are using multiple threads, you may have deadlock somewhere.